# Filter specific months in several years

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var x1= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(geometry)
                  .filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-10-30')
                  .sort('CLOUD_COVER');
```

How could I filter the dates in Sep, Oct, and Nov between 2014 and 2020?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to filter by year, then specific months within those years.

```js
// Create image collection of S-2 imagery for the perdiod 2015-2020
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

//filter start and end date
.filterDate('2015-07-01', '2020-10-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(9, 11,'month'))
```